# Oracle SQL ORA-00937: not a single-group group function

Tags: sql, oracle, function, group-by

I am trying to search for accounts which are of type 'Savings' but the following extract of code is giving me error "ORA-00937: not a single-group group function" - does anyone know why I am getting this error?

```
SELECT b.bID as "Branch Number", COUNT(a.accNum) as "# of Saving Accounts"
from branchtable b, accounttable a
where a.bId = b.bID
and a.acctype = 'Savings';
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need a "group by" clause:

```
SELECT b.bID as "Branch Number", 
     COUNT(a.accNum) as "# of Saving Accounts" 
from 
     branchtable b, accounttable a 
where 
     a.bId = b.bID and a.acctype = 'Savings'
group by b.bID;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT b.bID as "Branch Number", COUNT(a.accNum) as "# of Saving Accounts"
from branchtable b, accounttable a
where a.bId = b.bID
and a.acctype = 'Savings'
GROUP BY b.bID;
```

PS: Whatever columns you use in the SELECT clause except aggregate functions should be present in the GROUP BY clause.It's a blind rule.